# What does the phrase "achingly beautiful" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Can someone explain the phrase "achingly beautiful"? I often find myself reaching for it, while being unsure how to break down the meaning of it.

Comment: It would normally be interpreted to mean that the beauty is so extreme that it almost seems to cause pain -- it makes your heart ache.  The sort of thing that might be said of an extremely attractive person of the opposite sex.

Comment: I like this answer better than the one currently below! Want to add it as answer? If not I will

Comment: Your comparison to an extremely attractive person of the opposite sex also makes me realize there's an element of longing and even sadness in aching beauty. Perhaps it's tied up with the recognition that we're mortal (and often caught up in the mundane) so don't get to experience the aching beauty of life and the world as much as we'd like.

Comment: By "reaching for it", I take it that *you* are using the term. In that case, you're in a much better position than we are to explain what *you* mean by the term.

Comment: @Lawrence, that's not always the case - often one can't articulate or spell out what one means. Sometimes it's helpful to look up a word one knows how to use in a dictionary, to see an articulation of what one means! In philosophy, this is the distinction between 'knowledge how' and 'knowledge that'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**achingly**  [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/achingly)

adverb [ADV adj/adv]

> You can use **achingly** for emphasis when you are referring to things
>   that create feelings of wanting something very much, but of not being
>   able to have it. [written, emphasis] As in ... **three achingly
>   beautiful ballads**.

beautiful - no definition needed

> This is one of the most **achingly beautiful** cars in the world. The Sun
>   (2007),

but you cannot have one!